# where is "g:Tile 11" directory created?

Tags: c#, .net

I created a directory using system.io with path "g:Tile 11", I purposely did not put backslash , I was expecting that an error will be thrown, but directory is created and I can save more content in it and can also read this directory through code, But I am not able to find it in  windows file explorer. Does anyone know where are such files saved and how to read it in windows file explorer ?

Note: Its important that the g drive is available else it throws error

Comment: Maybe in the debug or release folder where your project runs, however the program must give you an exception

Comment: I believe this will create a directory within your current directory on that drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems when testing it with this:

```
DirectoryInfo d = Directory.CreateDirectory("c:Tile 11");
```

It *does* work. It just seems to strip off the `c:` from the path and create a `Tile 11` folder inside the `Debug` folder. (Check `d.FullName` to get the actual path)

Comment: As I said in my comment, it uses the current directory for that drive.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems impossible due to the path limitations on Windows. But apparently .NET tries to be smart for some reason.

Comment: This should without doubt throw an exception. This isn't the kind of functionality that should be 'hidden' from the developer. +1 for answer.

Comment: I guess it's equivalent to `g:` then `mkdir somedir`

Comment: If I use a drive prefix that doesn't exist it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If it is console or desktop based application then check bin/Debug folder of your application, if you don't set current directory.